# How to add more 'owners' to a gem in RubyGem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to add a new *owner* of a gem in RubyGem but I don't know where I should do this:

- in the .gemspec?
- in any place in RubyGems.org page?

I have tried to use the *gemspec options*:

- s.authors
- s.email

But still not seeing my *co-owner*.

For a concrete example I'm trying with this gem:

- https://rubygems.org/gems/evax
- https://github.com/SponsorPay/Evax/blob/master/evax.gemspec

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It's done with the gem command, see [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_owner)

```
gem owner my_gem -a foo@example.com
```

Comment: For info, this command don't touch the gem. It just communicate with rubygems.org to add (-a) ownership of the gem to an account. In the end, you both have ownership.